# When it comes to some repetitive/repetitious (words / excuses) in an argument

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Let's imagine you are arguing with someone pursuant to an old matter after a short time gap. Some new events make you feel that you will probably hear some new excuses/words from the person you are arguing with. But again he starts talking about the same old words and just repeats the excuses he/she had made before!
What would you say here as a disapproval?

> — These are all **repetitive** words/excuses. 
>   — These are all **repetitious** words/excuses.

Also, I wonder if it would be possible to say:

> - Your words / excuses have become **repetitive** to me.
> - Your words / excuses have become **repetitious** to me.

Based on dictionaries, they both work semantically, but I guess they are not the ways a native would say the same thing.

**Repetitive:**

> - Involvingdoing or saying the same thing several times, especially in a way that is boring:
> - A repetitive job/task.

**Repetitious:**

> - Filled with unnecessary and boring things expressed or happening in the same way many times:
> - The movie got a little repetitious after the third car chase.

Comment: See [“Repetitive” vs. “repetitious”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28981/repetitive-vs-repetitious) and [Historical use of 'repetitive' and 'repetitious' in BE/AE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187957/historical-use-of-repetitive-and-repetitious-in-be-ae) as previously asked on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "repetitive" and "repetitious" stem from the same root.  Both are common.  One is somewhat newer, although both are so old that they're part of the standard English lexicon.  From the etymology dictionary:

> **[repetitive](https://www.etymonline.com/word/repetitive)** (adj):  1805, from Latin *repetit-*, past participle stem of *repetere* "do or say again" (see repeat (v.)) + -ive.  repetitiveness.
>
> **[repetitious](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=repetitious)** (adj): "employing repetition," often with suggestions of tiresomeness, 1670s, from Latin *repetit-*, past participle stem of *repetere* "do or say again" (see repeat (v.)) + -ous.

"Repetitious" includes the slight nuance of "becoming tiresome or annoying", but you can imply the same thing with "repetitive" without much additional context, e.g. a ["*repetitive* stress injury"](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/repetitive-strain-injury-rsi/).

Either is fine in the context of your statement:

> Your argument is getting **repetitive**.
>
> Your argument is getting **repetitious**.

Or use the verb:

> You keep **repeating** the same argument.

---

Side note:  Try checking the [etymology dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/) as well as the others.  It may give you some additional clues about the differences (or lack thereof) between similar words.